deleting files from firebase storage cloud
I am having problems deleting firebase storage files from firebase functions. The purpose of the code is to delete profile image and banner image once the user decides to delete its profile.
I have little experience with python
Here is my code
from asyncio.log import logger
import firebase_admin
import firebase_admin.auth
import google.cloud.firestore as t
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, auth
import firebase_admin.storage as databasephotos


from firebase_admin import messaging, db
from firebase_functions import firestore_fn

from google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_query import FieldFilter

import asyncio


cred = credentials.Certificate({mycredentials})
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {  "storageBucket" : "appname.appspot.com"
})


@firestore_fn.on_document_created(document=r"UserDeletes/{id}")
def delete_user(event: firestore_fn.Event[firestore_fn.DocumentSnapshot | None]) -> None:
    adminpass = firebase_admin.auth
    database_updates_before_deletion = firestore.client()
    

    databasephotos.bucket(f'profileImage/profileImage/{event.data.get('userid')}').delete_blob('profileImage') #profilepic
    databasephotos.bucket(f'bannerImage/bannerImage/{event.data.get('userid')}').delete_blob('bannerImage') #bannerpic

when I do firebase functions:log, this erros comes DELETE 404 ERROR ../profileImage/profileImage/HZAznUo4cDUmfTSoMoQFPCKYAQi2/o/profileImage?prettyPrint=false: Not Found
one thing I notice is that the folder 'o' is added to the path, and the prettyPrint=false also gets added to the path.
Tried to ask chatgpt, this is code chatgpt produced
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': 'your-project-id.appspot.com'
})

def delete_file_from_firebase(file_path):
    # Get a reference to the storage bucket
    bucket = storage.bucket()

    # Get a blob (file) from the bucket
    blob = bucket.blob(file_path)

    # Delete the blob (file)
    blob.delete()

    print(f"File {file_path} deleted successfully.")

# Example usage
file_path = 'path/to/your/file.txt'
delete_file_from_firebase(file_path)


which I think is similar to mine.
here are the rules I have for firebase storage
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write : if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}

should I add allow delete permissions too?
spend a couple of hours trying and searching answers but none seem to be working for me.
I can add files normally and read them, but not delete them even with admin credentials.
UPDATE
Some of the solutions I found, not involving python, involved the use of the url token given to each file in firebasestorage.
You get the url, and delete from url. Spend another couple of hours and did not found a solution in python. They are possible in node.js and pyrebase.
I decided to implement the deletion in the client side using dart and flutter
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(userModel.profileImage).delete();

FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(userModel.bannerImage).delete(); 


I would prefer the account deletion to be completely on the server side and not the client side when it comes to deleting things. I think it might cause problems some way or another if some operations are done in the client side.
I problaby end up implementing the deletions using other non-python approach in the server side, but for now I will manually delete them once the user deletes. But if anyone has a solution in python let me know!

If you have more information to add, please edit the question instead of leaving it in comments.

Found the problem.
So chatgpt is correct, my problem was this line of code
databasephotos.bucket(f'profileImage/profileImage/{event.data.get('userid')}').delete_blob('profileImage') #profilepic

I had to use this instead
databasephotos.bucket().delete_blob(f'profileImage/profileImage/{event.data.get('userid')}/profileImage')

I was mistaking the method bucket(). So when you want to reference a file in firebasestorage, you have to use blob(#the path starts here)
Hope it helps anyone that made the same mistake as me when trying to reference a file.

Please review the SO policy on AI-generated content here and here.
